# Is there a way to make the Visual Studio Code window transparent?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A have a small resolution on my PC so it's not very convenient to work with several tabs open at the same time, like having an open console window, a browser, a code editor, and some other stuff.

Console has a very cool feature: a transparent background. So, it's very very comfortabe to type something on the console while looking to some learning material in the browser through the transparent background.

I guess if there is a way to make VS Code transparent so I can write code and research in the browser at the same time, instead of Alt-Tabing any time I have to switch, so I dont have to interrupt my workflow often.

Comment: I filed this as feedback on the VSCode GitHub project https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12578

Answer (score 27):

Use VS Code extension

> GlassIt-VSC

[image]
search in extension search bar

just install and enjoy
it works great !

Comment: Windows only says even the description of this extension.

Comment: @Jos It supports linux now.

Comment: Note: It makes whole window transparent, both background and font.

Answer (score 11):

Don't know about other OS but Windows can make any window transparent.

I've tried several 3rd party apps and stopped on [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) (free, Open-source, easy to learn, can be used for much more).

1. Install AutoHotkey
2. Create file `transparency.ahk`
3. Place inside this file:

```conf
^!RButton::
WinGet, currentTransparency, Transparent, A
if (currentTransparency = OFF)
{
    WinSet, Transparent, 150, A
}
else
{
    WinSet, Transparent, OFF, A
}
return
```

4. Run the script

   This script will toggle active window transparency(0-255, 0 - transparent, 255 - opaque)

   on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right mouse button</kbd>

   ^ - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

   ! - <kbd>Alt</kbd>

   RButton - <kbd>Right mouse button</kbd>
5. Add this script to startup folder (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `shell:common startup`)

   [image]

Based on: https://superuser.com/questions/272812/simple-transparency-toggle-with-autohotkey

Comment: Note: It makes whole window transparent, both background and font.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know - this isn't possible in e.g. Visual Studio Express or VS Code.

It seems not to be on the feature request list at Microsoft.

One solution I see for you is Notepad++. Install the `TopMost` add-in. It works like you can see in following screenshot:

[image: Notepad++ - Code Editor sample and transparency:]

Answer (score 3):

All the possible solutions are in:

- "[How to be cool and make Visual Studio Code (VSCode) transparent](https://dev.to/emmanuelnk/how-to-be-cool-and-make-vscode-transparent-56ib) " from [Emmanuel N Kyeyune](https://dev.to/emmanuelnk)

Mainly:

> ### Windows 10
>
> Install the [GlassIt-VSC extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=s-nlf-fh.glassit)
>
> In the VSCode settings (File > Preferences > Settings OR Ctrl + ,):
>
> - `glassit.alpha` (integer): Transparency level [1-255]
> - `glassit.step` (integer): Increment of alpha OR:
>
>   - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to increase transparency and
>   - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to decrease it as set by the extension
>     (take care it doesn't override some other shortcuts assigned these hotkeys)
>
> ### Linux (tested on Ubuntu 18.04)
>
> Based on [`devilspie`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie)
> sudo apt-get install devilspie
> with instruction like:
>
> ```
> ( if
> ( contains ( window_class ) "Code" )
> ( begin
> ( spawn_async (str "xprop -id " (window_xid) " -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 0xdfffffff") )
> )
> )
> ```

- [PR 52707 "Windows, macOS and Linux transparency"](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/52707) from [Charles Milette (`sylveon`)](https://github.com/sylveon).

The PR has been closed in August 2019:

> We currently do not accept more features that are Electron specific. We have seen to many issues lately when updating to newer Electron versions and playing the catch-up game is very painful.

But said PR still includes a ton of options, like the [Vibrancy extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32257#issuecomment-510882772).

---

Update Dec. 2021:

[Chaim Eliyah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2496266/chaim-eliyah) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031369/visual-studio-code-transparent-window/59592199?noredirect=1#comment124442717_59592199):

> Vibrancy "works" for Mac OS X; it modifies the base CSS files so Microsoft will forever complain about your VSCode installation
> (they tell you how to ignore the warning [in the `README`](https://github.com/EYHN/vscode-vibrancy#warning))

Comment: Vibrancy "works" for Mac OS X; it modifies the base CSS files so Microsoft will forever complain about your VSCode installation (they tell you how to ignore the warning in the README).

Comment: @ChaimEliyah Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. I have added the README link you mention: let me know if this is the correct one.

Comment: Awesome sauce!!

Comment: Note: It makes whole window transparent, both background and font.

Comment: @AgainPsychoX Thank you for the feedback. I don't suppose there is any way to be more specific when using that feature?

Answer (score 0):

If your in Linux(Debian), Install this: [Glassit Linux](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nowsci.glassit-linux)

Don't remember Install requirements:

```bash
sudo apt install -y wmctrl x11-utils bash
```