# How to fix VS Code displaying as see-through or transparent?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to fix this display issue? It seems blurred. I simply opened my VS Code after a night and here is the result. I have tried many ways to fix this error but I cannot. I have tried to change the High-DPI Display Scaling but it does not work.

[image]

Comment: restart your computer

Comment: try this shortcut `CTRL + ALT + C`. And check if you have `GlassIt-VSC` extension installed. Additionaly, check the following link as well [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031369/visual-studio-code-transparent-window)

Comment: how helpful is the question title for other people having the same problem, will they search, if they search at all, for `happy help me`

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have installed [GlassIt-VSC](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=s-nlf-fh.glassit) extension in your VS Code.
Uninstalling it will solve the problem.