# How to fix transparent VS Code context menu on web?

Tags: visual-studio-code, home-assistant, vs-code-settings

I use VS Code Server as a Home Assistant integration, but I think, as it is based on VS Code Web, there should be no difference. I have just installed it, and right from the beginning, the context menu looks transparent. I can't imagine this would be helpful for someone. Is this a weird setting or extension, like in this thread?:

[How to fix VS Code displaying as see-through or transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76857254/how-to-fix-vs-code-displaying-as-see-through-or-transparent)

Or do you think it is a Home Assistant-related bug?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajOC5.png)

I looked up the GlassIt-VSC extension but it is uninstalled.

Comment: Is it this bug?: [Context Menu background color becomes transparent when using the Dark Reader chrome extension](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/4163)

Comment: Yes, thank you. It was indeed this bug. I didn't consider DarkReader to be the problem. I added my Home Assistant URL to the blacklist of DarkReader, and it works flawlessly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, this is caused by the Dark Reader Chrome extension. See [[Bug] Context Menu background color becomes transparent when using the Dark Reader chrome extension
#4163](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/4163) (which is a miscategorization to say it's a Monaco / VS Code bug, since it's not VS Code's fault- it's caused by an unsupported browser extension (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/4163#issuecomment-1748920690))). A new issue ticket has been opened under the dark reader repo at [[Broken Website] Monaco context menu background color becomes transparent #11806](https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader/issues/11806).